# About the inequality $\frac{1}{2}>|\frac{z}{c}|, \forall z\in K.$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $c\geq 2 diam(K)$, where $K$ is compact in $\mathbb C$. Show that $\frac{1}{2}>|\frac{z}{c}|, \forall z\in K.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement as written is false: take $K$ to be the unit ball centered at the point $(100,0)$ for instance. But it becomes true if we add the hypothesis $0\in K$, and also replace the strict inequality with a $\geq $.

**Proof:**

Observe that $|z|\leq\text{diam}(K)$ for all $z\in K$. Indeed, this follows because $|z|=d(z,0)\leq \text{diam}(K)$. Since $c\geq 2\text{diam}(K)$, it follows that
$$
\left|\frac{z}{c}\right|\leq \left|\frac{z}{2\cdot \text{diam}(K)}\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Tnks @pre-kidney!